# Setting Background of a Div in a Repeater?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, background, repeater

First post here. I am trying to set the background image of a DIV within a asp:repeater. The image will need to change with each repeating DIV item and therefore I need to return the image URL from the database.

I can set it every time to the same image by hard coding the URL into the DIV like below:

```
    <asp:Repeater ID="repList" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="repList_ItemDataBound">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div id="bGContainer" runat="server" class="formLayout" style=" background-position:Left; width:980; background-image: url(images/image1.jpg);">
  <div class="innerDiv">
  <asp:Image ID="imgImage1" runat="server" />
  </div>
</div>
```

however, what I am trying to do in the code behind is set the background to each bGContainer to the image I have within the dataset.

Here is my code behind that sets the value to an ASP:image that appears within the inner DIV:

```
 protected void repList_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Item.DataItem != null)
            {
                OnlineList currentOnlineList = (OnlineList)e.Item.DataItem;

                imgImage1.ImageUrl = currentOnlineList.imageUrl;
            }
        }
```

So what I am trying to do is somehow call the bgContainer DIV and set the backgroundimage to a value in a value I return in my list.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you cant access imgImage1 directly. you have to find the control like this.

```
  System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image img=(System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image)e.Item.FindControl("imgImage1");
    img.ImageUrl= currentOnlineList.imageUrl;
```